# Custom HTML elements and Markdown parsing

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I have defined a number of custom HTML elements `<my-element1>`, `<my-element2>` (in JavaScript via `extends HTMLElement`) ... and inside these elements, I am writing Markdown that needs to be parsed:

```html
<!-- no parsing inside this element -->
<my-element1>
This is *markdown* with a bit of `code`.
</my-element1>
```

However, the markdown is not being parsed.

The standard solution seems to be to set the attribute `markdown="1"` inside an HTML element to inform the kramdown parser that whatever is inside the element should be parsed. And this works **if** I am using a standard HTML element:

```html
<!-- parsing goes ok -->
<div markdown="1">
This is *markdown* with a bit of `code`.
</div>
```

However, setting this attribute in a custom HTML element has no effect. The ugly workaround is to always add `<div>` (or other standard) tags inside my custom elements. But of course, that is not ideal. Does anyone know a better solution to this problem? Is there a setting inside Jekyll that can inform kramdown of which additional HTML elements have been defined?